# Simple Cryption Function in C

Tags: c, encryption

I want to create a simple encryption algorithm but I couldn't do it yet. When I run this program, it was typing on screen

```
"Name: John Nash, Cryptioned Data: John Nash, Decryptioned Data: John Nash"
```

How can I solve this problem? Where am I making a mistake?

```
#include<stdio.h>


char *ecrypt(char data[]);
char *decrypt(char data[]);

int i; // Global variable...

void main(void)
{
    char name[] = "John Nash",*data_encryptioned,*data_decryption;
    data_encryptioned = ecrypt(name);
    data_decryption = decrypt(data_encryptioned);
    printf("Name: %s, Cryptioned Data: %s, Decryptioned Data: %s\n",name,data_encryptioned,data_decryption);
}

char *ecrypt(char data[])
{
    for(i=0;data[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        data[i]+=i+12;
    }
    return &data[0];
}

char *decrypt(char data[])
{
    for(i=0;data[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        data[i]-=(i+12);
    }
    return &data[0];
}
```

Comment: All 3 of your pointers are pointing to the same location in memory. Try malloc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the same buffer that's been encrypted and decrypted before you print. So either make a copy of the encrypted string or print them in steps to see the process:

```
    printf("%s\n", name);
    data_encryptioned = ecrypt(name);
    printf("Cryptioned Data: %s\n",data_encryptioned);
    data_decryption = decrypt(data_encryptioned);
    printf("Decryptioned Data: %s\n",data_decryption);
```